# Image carousel (images as radiobuttons in carousel) HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, radio-button, carousel

I have a view on which a carousel should be displayed that contains images as radio buttons. I have managed the carousel, but unfortunately the radiobuttons do not work.

I have the following code on my view:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6" style="position: relative;">
        <p class="format">Pick your Art Style</p>
        <div class="gallery-carousel" id="gallery">
            @foreach (var style in styles)
            {
                <label for="@style.Key" class="radio-label">
                    <input type="radio" name="style" id="@style.Key" class="radio-button" value="@style.Key" />
                    <img src="@style.Value">
                    @style.Key
                </label>
            };
        </div>
        <button class="button-carousel scroll-left" onclick="scrollGallery(-450)"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left"></i></button>
        <button class="button-carousel scroll-right" onclick="scrollGallery(450)"><i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right"></i></button>

        <script>
            function scrollGallery(offset) {
                const gallery = document.getElementById("gallery");
                gallery.scrollTo({
                    left: gallery.scrollLeft + offset,
                    behavior: "smooth"
                });
            }
        </script>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3"></div>
</div>
```

This represents a carousel that contains images that should work as radiobuttons. Unfortunately only the hover and clicking on the images as radionbuttons does not work.

[image]

Here is the CSS for it:

```
.ai-generate-generate-product .radio-label {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.ai-generate-generate-product .radio-button {
    display: none;
}

.ai-generate-generate-product .radio-label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

    .ai-generate-generate-product .radio-label:hover {
        background-color: #d1d1d1;
    }

.ai-generate-generate-product .radio-button:checked + .radio-label {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    border: 1px solid white;
}

.ai-generate-generate-product .gallery-carousel {
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-size: 0;
}

.ai-generate-generate-product .scroll-left {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ai-generate-generate-product .scroll-right {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 30px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.ai-generate-generate-product .button-carousel {
    color: black;
    top: 50%;
    background-color: #00000000;
    font-size: 30px;
    border: none;
}

.ai-generate-generate-product img {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

I would also like a text to be displayed under the image.